# How can I include pod startup logs/information in CD output?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment

I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline. The deployment step runs these commands:

```
kubectl apply -f manifest.yml --namespace <namespace>
kubectl rollout status Deployment/<service> --namespace <namespace>
```

This gives the following output:

```
Waiting for deployment "<service>" rollout to finish: 1 out of 2 new replicas have been updated...
error: deployment "<service>" exceeded its progress deadline
##[error]error: deployment "<service>" exceeded its progress deadline
```

By running

```
kubectl get pods
```

I can see it has started a pod which is stuck in CrashLoopBackOff. I can see why the pod failed to start by running:

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

Is there a way to include this output in the deployment log? I can obviously check if the deployment failed, then parse the above commands and display the log output, but I would hope there's some way to get this information out of kubectl rollout status (preferably if there were a way to make kubectl rollout status notify whenever a pod in the deployment had a status change, and show logs for any pods with an error status change.)

Comment: Looks like you can do `kubectl logs deployment/<service>`. I'm not sure how that behaves in the middle of a rollout, and if it provides the experience you're looking for. You could try having `kubectl rollout status` in one terminal pane and `kubectl logs` for the whole deployment in the other. I'd be curious if you find that helpful, I haven't yet used `kubectl logs` against a whole deployment myself.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not already the case, [labelize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) you pod :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: label-demo
  labels:
    environment: production
    app: nginx
```

It enables you to see the logs without the pod name :

```
kubectl logs -l app=nginx -n your-namespace
```

For the `CrashLoopBackOff` error, events give often more information than the logs :

```
kubectl get events --sort-by lastTimestamp -n your-namespace
```

Add this at this end of your pipeline, it will give you interesting information about your pod scheduling, ect...

Comment: That's helpful. It's still very frustrating that I have to wait for the deployment to timeout before the deployment will actually fail from really obvious configuration errors. I'm considering disabling auto-replacement of dead pods during the deployment, then re-enabling in another step but that's also rather worrisome since if there's an error it could leave the service in an at-risk state.

Comment: Weirdly, kubectl logs -l app=nginx -n your-namespace seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes the deployment completes but then I get an error like `Error from server (BadRequest): container "mycontainer" in pod "my-pod-zzzz-zzzz" is terminated` I think somehow it decides to try and grab logs for the old pod that is going away, rather than the new pods. But they're supposed to be ready when the rollout is done? Very strange.